# Vibrating string and Fourier series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Exercise 19 and 20(page 622) in differential equations and boundary value problems EDWARDS & PENNEY says the following:

> Problems $19$ and $20$ deal with the vibrations of a string under the
>   influence of the downward force $F(x)=-pg$ of gravity. According to
>   Eq. ($1$), its displacement function satisfies the partial differential
>   equation
>
> $$\frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial t^{2}}=a^{2}\frac{\partial^{2} y}{\partial x^{2}}-g \quad(40)$$
>
> with endpoint conditions $y(0,t)=y(L,t)=0$.
>
> $19$. Suppose first that the string hangs in a stationary position, so that $y=y(x)$ and $y_{tt}=0$. Hence its differential equation of
>   motion takes the simple form $a^{2}y''=g$. Derive the stationary
>   solution $$y(x)=\Phi (x)=\frac{gx}{2a^{2}}(x-L)$$
>
> $20$. Now suppose that the string is released from rest in equilibrium. Consequently the initial conditions are $y(x,0)=0$ and
>   $y_{t}(x,0)=0$. Define
>
> $$v(x,t)=y(x,t)-\Phi (x)$$
>
> where $\Phi (x)$ is the stationary solution of problem $19$. Deduce from Eq. ($40$) that $v(x,t)$ satisfies the boundary value problem
>
> \begin{align}
> v_{tt} &= a^{2}v_{xx} \\
> v(0,t) &= v(L,t) = 0 \\
> v(x,0) &= -\Phi (x)\\
> v_{t}(x,0) &= 0
> \end{align}
>
> Conclude from Eqs. ($22$) and ($23$) that
>
> $$y(x,t) - \Phi (x) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} \cos \left(\frac{n\pi at}{L} \right) \sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right)$$
>
> where the coefficients $A_{n} $ are the Fourier sine coefficients of $f(x)=-\Phi (x)$. Finally, explain why it follows that the string oscillates
>   between the positions $y = 0$ and $y = 2 \Phi (x)$.

I don't know how to show that the string oscillates between $y=0$ and $y=2\Phi (x)$.

I know that

$$y(x,t)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} \cos \left(\frac{n\pi at}{L} \right) \sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right)+\Phi (x)$$

and

$$\Phi (x)= \sum -A_{n} \sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right)$$

is Fourier sine series of $\Phi$, then

\begin{align}
y(x,t) &= \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } - A_{n} \sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right) \left[1 - \cos \left(\frac{n\pi at} {L} \right) \right] \\
&= 2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } - A_{n} \sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right) \sin^{2} \left(\frac{n\pi at}{2L} \right)
\end{align}

I would appreciate if anyone can help

Comment: What are equations $22$ and $23$? And did you derive the solution yourself? It should make things clear.

Comment: @Mattos sorry, i forgot to write the equations 22 and 23 are $A_{n}=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f(x)sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})dx$ and $y_{A}(x,t)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }A_{n}cos(\frac{n\pi at} {L})sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$,formal series solution of problem $y_{tt}=a^{2}y_{xx}$; $y(0,t)=y(L,t)=0$; $y(x,0)=f(x)$; $y_{t}(x,0)=0$.I was able to get the solution in 19 and show that $v(x,t)$ satisfies the problem